# Reputation score for grounded users

Tags: support, reputation

I see score of one user is showing 1 while I know he was in 2700 before. I know he got grounded for not obeying SO policies. My question is how does the scoring work, when you are grounded for some time?

The user page shows many honors and badges but a score of 1? What are the scoring rules when someone gets grounded? Will this user loose all his points forever?

Comment: I've removed the image, we generally don't like discussing users without their permission :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the score stays at 1 for the duration of the suspension. It goes back to the original value afterwards.

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how * long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.
>
> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

[A Day in the Penalty Box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: A quick question, you might or might not know. If your answers or question during that period are voted up/down, I guess those will be taken into account when the penalty ends?

Comment: Yes they will. 1